# Ruby on Rails Michael Hartl Chapter 6.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When loading the Rails console in sandbox as following the tutorial, i can't create a new user object ? I've got this message :

```
>> User.new

NameError: uninitialized constant User
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/Genosia/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /Users/Genosia/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/Genosia/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /Users/Genosia/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Genosia/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Genosia/code/sample_app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Genosia/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/Genosia/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you run both the model generator, and the migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have a user class in your app/models folder.

You can use the rails generator for that:

```
bundle exec rails g model user name:string date_of_birth:date ...
```

That will create the model under `app/models` and the migration under `db/migrate`

To run the migrations run

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rails c --sandbox
```

Then it should work.

Note that opening the console in sandbox mode will rollback all the database changes when you close it.

To have persistent changes run

`bundle exec rails c`